# How to ask for clarification on a very old answer

Tags: discussion

Hello I recently was reading [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232990/are-there-any-known-negative-heat-capacities) and the top [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/232996/339095) had this line “Remember that you cannot do classical thermodynamics without equilibrium anyway.” I want an explanation of this line. The answer was made 6 years ago and the answerer’s account seems to have been deleted. So commenting on the answer won’t help.

I guess I feel my question is too trivial to make a new post.

I searched a bit and [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/135647/339095) just keeps defining what thermal equilibrium *is*. What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Just ask a follow-up question.

If you feel like your request for clarification is "too trivial," then spend a few minutes trying write down an answer for yourself. Either you'll succeed (great!) or you'll get stuck on something more specific, which you can use in making the nature of your follow-up question clearer.

Similarly, if you are finding other material (answers, books, etc.) which seems like it ought to be helpful but isn't, some explanation of what that other material says versus what you *wish* it said will help the community to understand what the meat of your follow-up question is.